# Kendo Chart shows Incorrect results on Google Chrome. But correct result in Firefox?

Tags: c#, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dataviz

I have a report which generates chart.I am showing this report on pre defined data set.

[image: Data In Chrome]
[image: Data in Mozilla]

First Image is from chrome browser.Second is from firefox.Firefox shows the correct data. But chrome is showing incorrect. you can see the month order.

I went through [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582184/how-to-solve-incorrect-grouped-bar-chart-in-chrome) question in StackOverflow. 
still I got the result similar to first image.
anyone came up with these sort of issue ??

```
  setDataSource: function (jsonData) {
            myDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: jsonData,
                group: [{ "field": "Series" }],
                sort: [{ "field": "Series", dir: "asc" },  { "field": "SortOrder", dir: "asc" }],
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            Category: {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            Series: {
                                "type": "number"
                            },
                            Value: {
                                "type": "number"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        },

        setupChart: function (id) {
            $("#chart" + id).kendoChart({
                dataSource: myDataSource,
                title: {
                    text: "@Lables.LBL_PlanningProjection"
                },
                legend: {
                    position: "top"
                },
                chartArea: {
                    background: ""
                },
                seriesDefaults: {
                    type: "line"
                },
                series: [{
                    field: "Value"
                }],
                valueAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        format: "{0:N0}"
                    },
                    line: {
                        visible: true
                    },
                    majorUnit: 10000
                },
                categoryAxis: {
                    field: "Category",
                    labels: {
                        template: "#: value #",
                        rotation: 0
                    },
                    majorGridLines: {
                        visible: false
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    format: "{0}",
                    template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Am I missing something obvious, or is the SortOrder in `{ "field": "SortOrder", dir: "asc" }` undefined?  Judging by the thread you linked to, SortOrder should be replaced with either Category or Value.

Comment: Please put your code into a live demo so that we can help to deal it.

Comment: @sculper, SortOrder is coming from server side.

Comment: If I replaced SortOrder with Category it is sorted by alphabetic order of the months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem occurs with Chrome's implementation of `Array.sort`;
You can fix it by sorting the data source explicitly here.

And as I can see in your code, there is a field named **SortOrder** here. I think in the original code that you have get this, used that field to sort the dataset explicitly.

Check your Controller or Back-End code inorder to find the SortOrder property. If not you can add that in your back-end logic to sort your dataset explicitly according to the month order.

As I can see you can't do a explicit sort here by adding following line.

```
 sort: [{ "field": "Series", dir: "asc" },  { "field": "Category", dir: "asc" }],
```

Because it 'll get your data set sorted as the first image.

```
Apr , Aug, Dec , Feb , Jan , Jul , Jun, Mar , May, Nov , Oct, Sep
```

I think that's why the original code has a property called `SortOrder`.